# Get User IP in PHP and cURL to Remote File

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that I want to grab the visitor IP when they access the file then using cURL to POST the user IP on a remote file on a different server. I know how to receive the variable on the remote server but don't know how to use cURL to post the user IP on the file located on another site. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Comment: Set the option CURLOPT_POST, and set the query data via the option CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.